# React FontAwesome Icons don't like Material-UI Tooltips

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

Consider this code:

```
<div className="p-2">
  <Tooltip
    arrow
    title={(
      <div>
        <h6>
          Delete
          {' '}
          {tool.toolName}
          {' '}
          Tool
        </h6>
      </div>
    )}
  >
    <DeleteButtonIcon
      id={`delete_${tool.toolId}`}
      onClick={() => { setOpenModal(tool) }}
      className="fa-2x"
    />
  </Tooltip>
</div>
```

```
export const DeleteButtonIcon = ({
  className,
  id,
  onClick
}: { className?, id?: string, onClick?(event: any): any }): JSX.Element => (
  <FaWhite2rem
    icon={faTrash}
    className={className}
    id={id}
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
  />
)
```

The Tooltips worked fine with Material-UI icons, they don't display with FontAwesome Icons.

I'm going to continue debugging this, thought I would place this here in case anyone has ever run into this.

If I figure out the fix before anyone answers I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the one of the possible fixes was super simple, you just need to wrap it in a div.

```
<div className="p-2">
  <Tooltip
    arrow
    title={(
      <div>
        <h6>
          Delete
          {' '}
          {tool.toolName}
          {' '}
          Tool
        </h6>
      </div>
    )}
  >
    <div>
      <DeleteButtonIcon
        id={`delete_${tool.toolId}`}
        onClick={() => { setOpenModal(tool) }}
        className="fa-2x"
      />
    </div>
  </Tooltip>
</div>
```

Having any type of parent element will work as well.